# Canvas to blob returns empty blob object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, blob

I'm trying to convert a canvas element image to blob. I have tried the below code using canvas-to-blob.min.js and it returns an empty object. But when converting to data URL it is not empty.

```
var file = getFile();
var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) {

   var img = new Image();

   img.onload = function () {

     var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
         canvas.height = height;
         canvas.width = width;
         var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d"); 
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,width,height);                        

    var data_URL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');   /* Returns correct data URL */

        if (canvas.toBlob) {
                         canvas.toBlob(
                                 function (blob) {

                                           console.log(JSON.stringify(blob)) /* Return empty */
                                            var formData = new FormData();
                                            formData.append('file', blob, fileName);
                                            /* ... */
                                        },
                                        'image/jpeg'
                                    );
                                }


        }

     img.src = this.result;

   }

 reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Also I have tried the dataURIToBlob() custom function like this (function not included here)

```
var data_URL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
var blob = dataURIToBlob(data_URL);
console,log(JSON.stringify(blob))   /* returns empty object */
```

The result is same emprty object. Please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blob Object's `type` and `size` properties are not enumerable, hence, `JSON.stringify` will ignore their values and return only a string representing an empty object : `"{}"`.

```js
var blob = new Blob(['hello world'], {type:'text/plain'});

console.log(JSON.stringify(blob));
console.log(blob);
```

I guess that your blob is well formed, you can send it like this.

Comment: i think i have a well formed blob but JSON.stringify is still just returning an emtpy object '{}'. the blob in the console log looks like:
Blob {size: 1996683, type: "image/png"}
size: 1996683
type: "image/png"
__proto__: Blob

any idea? also have the problem i cant save the blob in my typeorm database as blob.. its always saved empty dont know if both is related

Comment: @white91wolf That json.stringify returns an empty object is normal, that's what this answer says. For your db, I'm clueless.

Answer (score -1):

```
ResizeImage(file) {
    // Read in file
    var self=this;
    var file = file;

    var image = new Image();
    // Ensure it's an image
    if(file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
        // Load the image
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (readerEvent) {

            image.onload = function (imageEvent) {

                // Resize the image
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
                    max_size = 128,// TODO : pull max size from a site config
                    width = image.width,
                    height = image.height;
                if (width > height) {
                    if (width > max_size) {
                        height *= max_size / width;
                        width = max_size;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (height > max_size) {
                        width *= max_size / height;
                        height = max_size;
                    }
                }
                canvas.width = width;
                canvas.height = height;
                canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
                var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                var resizedImage = self.dataURItoBlob(dataUrl);
                $.event.trigger({
                    type: "imageResized",
                    blob: resizedImage,
                    url: dataUrl
                });
                self.setState({Thumb:resizedImage});
                console.log(resizedImage);
                console.log(self.state);
            }
            image.src = readerEvent.target.result;


        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }


}
dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
    // doesn't handle URLEncoded DataURIs - see SO answer #6850276 for code that does this
    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

    // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);

    // create a view into the buffer
    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);

    // set the bytes of the buffer to the correct values
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    // write the ArrayBuffer to a blob, and you're done
    var blob = new Blob([ab], {type: mimeString});
    return blob;

}
```